# Printer not print data after removing break point n debug mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, printing, xamarin.android

Here is my code for print data on bluetooth printer

```
using (BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = device?.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(serialUUID))
                            {
                                try
                                {

                                    if (!bluetoothSocket.IsConnected)
                                    {
                                        bluetoothSocket?.Connect();
                                    }

                                    string sss = " Sample Test Line \nSample Test Line";
                                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sss);
                                    bluetoothSocket?.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    bluetoothSocket.Close();
                                }
                                catch (System.Exception e)
                                {

                                }                           
                            }
```

when I test this code on debug mode,it only print when I set a break point on any of line.But after removing the break point it will not print anything.

how to solve this?

Comment: You are catching all exceptions but even not logging them... try just re-throwing that exception to rule out that you are hiding a problem. Also is anything reported in `logcat` on the device?

Comment: @SushiHangover why you didn't format the code in your edit?!